# a polynomial problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2011$ such that $P(1) = 0, P(2) = 1, P(4) = 2  $, ... ,  $P(2^{2011}) = 2011.$ Compute the coefficient of the $x^1$
term in $P(x)$.

I really don't have an idea where to even start this problem.. There are no simple form for this polynomial and I just can't rewrite this in a factorized form. Some help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I was young, there was an obvious point where to start with **every** problem: you grab pencil and paper, and start working. Nowadays, you grab a keyboard (or smartphone) and ask at MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may be more general. Let $n\geq 1$, and $P_n$ the (unique) polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P_n(2^j)=j$ for $0\leq j \leq n$. Put $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$. We want $a_1$. Let $Q(x)=(x-1)\prod_{j=2}^n (x-2^j)=\sum_{m=0}^n b_m x^m$.

We compute the sum $S$:
$$S=\sum_{m=0}^n b_m P_n(2^m)=\sum_{m=0}^n b_m(\sum_{l=0}^n a_l2^{ml})=\sum_{l=0}^n a_l(\sum_{m=0}^nb_m2^{ml})=\sum_{l=0}^n a_l Q(2^l)$$
and we have $S=a_1Q(2)$.

Now $$S=\sum_{m=0}^n b_m P_n(2^m)=\sum_{m=0}^n b_m m=Q^{\prime}(1)$$

Hence $\prod_{j=2}^n(1-2^j)=a_1\prod_{j=2}^n (2-2^j)$
and it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give another name for P. Let me call it $P_{2011}$. You can factorise it as $P_{2011} = (x-1)P_{2010}$ because $P_{2011}(1)=0$, right?

Then you know that $P_{2011}(2) = (2-1) *P_{2010}(2) =1$, so $P_{2010}(2)=1$.

Keep going.