Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2011$ such that $P(1) = 0, P(2) = 1, P(4) = 2, \dots, P(2^{2011}) = 2011.$
Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2011$ such that $P(1) = 0, P(2) = 1, P(4) = 2, \dots, P(2^{2011}) = 2011.$ Then the coefficient of $x$ in $P(x)$ can be expressed in the form $a -  \dfrac{1}{b^c}$, where $a,$ $b,$ $c$ are positive integers, and $b$ is prime. Find $a + b + c.$
My thoughts are defining $Q(x) = P(2x) - P(x) - 1$ but not sure how to proceed.
Any thoughts, lads?

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2595713/42969. Also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1296600p6884233 on AoPS.

Defining $Q(x) = P(2x) - P(x) - 1$ is almost the complete solution.
We have $Q(2^k) = 0$ for $k \in\{0 .. 2010\}$ giving us: $$Q(x)= c\prod_{n=0}^{2010}(x-2^n)$$ for some $c$ (as the degree of $Q(x)$ must be 2011). Combining with $Q(0) = -1$ we rewrite $Q$ as: $$Q(x)= -\prod_{n=0}^{2010}\frac{(x-2^n)}{-2^n} = -\prod_{n=0}^{2010}(1-\frac{x}{2^n})$$
The $x$ coefficient in $Q(x)$ is equal to the $x$ coefficient in $P(x)$ (due to $Q(x)= P(2x)-P(x)-1$) and by expanding the above formula, is equal to: $$-\sum_{n=0}^{2010}-\frac{1}{2^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{2010}\frac{1}{2^n} = 2-\frac{1}{2^{2010}}$$
Plugging in $a -  \dfrac{1}{b^c} = 2-\frac{1}{2^{2010}}$ gives $a = 2,b =2 , c = 2010$, and $a+b+c = 2014$.
